# flex - How to set the font of Label by setting android os?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts

1. I changed the device font in the android device: setting - display - font
2. I want to change the font of Labels my flex application automatically.
   In the android studio, It proceeds naturally.
   but, in flex application, it's not so.

How can I do this?

Comment: there is an option for text's, named smoothing, many available types provided but one of them is "use device font", you have to set this for text's inside the lable component's

Comment: Use the following font name; "_sans", it will automatically grab the default system font.

Comment: @Mr.Phantom, is that provide device emoji's support as well?

Comment: Adobe AIR has some issues with emojis. You can only see them when you use StageText and Flash TextField.